# on 12.04 & XP dual boot system, howto upgrade xp to win 7?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows

I have system with XP installed first, followed by Mint 12 and then Ubuntu 12.04. I now wish to remove Win XP and install Win 7 in the Win XP partition. How do I go about this?

Thanks for any help in the matter.

Comment: First of all we need to know if you have separate partitions or drives for each of the operating systems.

Comment: So at the moment you have a triple boot system?

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming you havent used wubi to install mint and Ubuntu.**

Install Win7 over XP partition.

Then restore grub by booting from a live cd like so:

--> Mount the linux partition ( Mint or Ubuntu . Both are fine)

-->`sudo grub-install --boot-directory=path-to-the-mounted-partition /dev/sdX`

(X = a, b or c depending on the name of the device . If you dont
    know it, then do `ls /dev/sd*`)

-->sudo update-grub2

Reboot.